# jupyter Kernel is busy all the time, How to debug

Tags: python, windows, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I create or run any notebook, the kernel keeps loading. I reinstalled the Miniconda and anaconda both as well but the kernel doesn't get set. Tried to change the browser as well. 
I'm not able to debug the issue. 
[jupyter notebook screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bm1S.png)

Here is the bug report I got:

```
[D 14:09:37.864 NotebookApp] Searching ['E:\installed_softwares', 'C:\Users\Admin\.jupyter', 'E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter', 'C:\ProgramData\jupyter'] for config files
[D 14:09:37.865 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 14:09:37.866 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 14:09:37.866 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\Admin.jupyter
[D 14:09:37.867 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in E:\installed_softwares
[D 14:09:37.868 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 14:09:37.869 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 14:09:37.869 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\Admin.jupyter
[D 14:09:37.869 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in E:\installed_softwares
[D 14:09:41.398 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
C:\ProgramData\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 14:09:41.400 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 14:09:41.401 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
C:\Users\Admin.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[I 14:09:41.698 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: E:\installed_softwares
[I 14:09:41.699 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 14:09:41.699 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:09:41.699 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=2929a5f4ef1d2e4ddcc14f22163ba2ff835817187a674e3c
[I 14:09:41.699 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:09:41.710 NotebookApp]
```

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=2929a5f4ef1d2e4ddcc14f22163ba2ff835817187a674e3c&token=2929a5f4ef1d2e4ddcc14f22163ba2ff835817187a674e3c

```
[I 14:09:41.831 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 14:09:41.855 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 14:09:42.023 NotebookApp] Path base/images/favicon.ico served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\base\images\favicon.ico
[D 14:09:42.024 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\jquery-ui\themes\smoothness\jquery-ui.min.css
[D 14:09:42.026 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\jquery-typeahead\dist\jquery.typeahead.min.css
[D 14:09:42.028 NotebookApp] Path style/style.min.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\style\style.min.css
[D 14:09:42.030 NotebookApp] Path components/es6-promise/promise.min.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\es6-promise\promise.min.js
[D 14:09:42.030 NotebookApp] Path components/preact/index.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\preact\index.js
[D 14:09:42.031 NotebookApp] Path components/proptypes/index.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\proptypes\index.js
[D 14:09:42.032 NotebookApp] Path components/preact-compat/index.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\preact-compat\index.js
[D 14:09:42.032 NotebookApp] Path components/requirejs/require.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\requirejs\require.js
[D 14:09:42.034 NotebookApp] Path base/images/logo.png served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\base\images\logo.png
[D 14:09:42.035 NotebookApp] Path tree/js/main.min.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\tree\js\main.min.js
[D 14:09:42.044 NotebookApp] 200 GET /tree?token=00b8107f6a0e9f6240ccd4772848978edf3fe631c9186cdb (::1) 216.06ms
[D 14:09:42.084 NotebookApp] Path custom.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css
[D 14:09:42.096 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 23.46ms
[D 14:09:43.143 NotebookApp] Path services\contents.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\services\contents.js
[D 14:09:43.146 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/services/contents.js?v=20180628140937 (::1) 4.89ms
[D 14:09:43.277 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree:
C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig\tree.json
[D 14:09:43.278 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree:
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\tree.json
[D 14:09:43.280 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree:
C:\Users\Admin.jupyter\nbconfig\tree.json
[D 14:09:43.281 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/tree?=1530175182919 (::1) 7.82ms
[D 14:09:43.286 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:43.288 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:43.289 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
C:\Users\Admin.jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:43.291 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?=1530175182920 (::1) 6.84ms
[D 14:09:43.309 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?=1530175182921 (::1) 0.98ms
[D 14:09:43.315 NotebookApp] Found kernel python3 in E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 14:09:43.323 NotebookApp] 304 GET /api/kernelspecs (::1) 9.78ms
[D 14:09:43.331 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?=1530175182923 (::1) 2.93ms
[D 14:09:43.335 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?=1530175182922 (::1) 2.93ms
[D 14:09:43.519 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&=1530175182924 (::1) 119.27ms
[D 14:09:43.525 NotebookApp] Path custom.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.js
[D 14:09:43.533 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.js?v=20180628140937 (::1) 9.78ms
[I 14:09:54.532 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[D 14:09:54.541 NotebookApp] Saving E:\installed_softwares\Untitled.ipynb
[D 14:09:54.816 NotebookApp] 201 POST /api/contents (::1) 296.22ms
[D 14:09:54.827 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 14:09:54.954 NotebookApp] Path base/images/favicon-notebook.ico served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\base\images\favicon-notebook.ico
[D 14:09:54.954 NotebookApp] Path components/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\bootstrap-tour\build\css\bootstrap-tour.min.css
[D 14:09:54.955 NotebookApp] Path components/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\codemirror\lib\codemirror.css
[D 14:09:54.955 NotebookApp] Path notebook/css/override.css served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\notebook\css\override.css
[D 14:09:55.324 NotebookApp] Path components/text-encoding/lib/encoding.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\text-encoding\lib\encoding.js
[D 14:09:55.325 NotebookApp] Path notebook/js/main.min.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\notebook\js\main.min.js
[D 14:09:55.334 NotebookApp] 200 GET /notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1) 510.31ms
[D 14:09:55.437 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\MathJax.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\MathJax.js
[D 14:09:55.439 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&delayStartupUntil=configured (::1) 3.91ms
[D 14:09:55.451 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 7.81ms
[D 14:09:55.531 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js
[D 14:09:55.533 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 2.93ms
[D 14:09:55.629 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\config\Safe.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\Safe.js
[D 14:09:55.631 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 3.91ms
[D 14:09:55.928 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of notebook:
C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json
[D 14:09:55.930 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of notebook:
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.d\widgetsnbextension.json
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json
[D 14:09:55.932 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of notebook:
C:\Users\Admin.jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json
[D 14:09:55.935 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/notebook?=1530175195674 (::1) 8.80ms
[D 14:09:55.940 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:55.941 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:55.943 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common:
C:\Users\Admin.jupyter\nbconfig\common.json
[D 14:09:55.944 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?=1530175195675 (::1) 6.84ms
[D 14:09:56.010 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\extensions\MathML\content-mathml.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\extensions\MathML\content-mathml.js
[D 14:09:56.011 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/extensions/MathML/content-mathml.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 1.96ms
[D 14:09:56.049 NotebookApp] Found kernel python3 in E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 14:09:56.052 NotebookApp] 304 GET /api/kernelspecs (::1) 3.91ms
[D 14:09:56.166 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/Untitled.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1530175195676 (::1) 84.08ms
[D 14:09:56.169 NotebookApp] Path jupyter-js-widgets\extension.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\nbextensions\jupyter-js-widgets\extension.js
[D 14:09:56.177 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\extensions\Safe.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\extensions\Safe.js
[D 14:09:56.180 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/extensions/Safe.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 4.89ms
[D 14:09:56.190 NotebookApp] Path components\MathJax\jax\output\HTML-CSS\fonts\STIX-Web\fontdata.js served from E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\jax\output\HTML-CSS\fonts\STIX-Web\fontdata.js
[D 14:09:56.193 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX-Web/fontdata.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 3.91ms
[D 14:09:56.203 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.js?v=20180628140937 (::1) 7.82ms
[D 14:09:56.402 NotebookApp] Starting kernel: ['E:\installed_softwares\Miniconda3\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-5bd7d628-e859-4045-b8ff-863972451827.json']
[D 14:09:56.410 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:62649
```